# Storing Python 3 Enum in MySQL using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, enums, sqlalchemy, python-3.6

When I try to store a `Animals` object with a field `species` containing a Python `Enum` object `SpeciesType.Cat`, I get the error

> TypeError: object of type 'VisitableType' has no len()

What is the correct way to store a Python 3 `Enum` in MySQL using SQLAlchemy?

```
# SQLALCHEMY CODE ########################

from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class SpeciesType(Enum):
    Cat = 1
    Dog = 2


class Animals(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'animals'
    id  = Column(String(16), primary_key=True)
    species = Column(Enum(SpeciesType))


# REGULAR CODE ########################

import enum

class SpeciesType(enum.Enum):
    Cat = 1
    Dog = 2


class MyClass:
    @property
    def session(self):
        ....

    def insertToDB(self):
        kitty = Animals(id='kitty', species=SpeciesType.Cat)
        self.session.add(kitty)
        self.session.commit()

c = MyClass()
c.insertToDB()
```

---

### Update

The following new error occurs after fixing the name collision between `sqlalchemy.enum` and `Enum.enum`.

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.LookupError) "SpeciesType.Cat" is not among the defined enum values [SQL: 'INSERT INTO animals (id, species) VALUES (%(id)s, %(species)s)'] [parameters: [{'species': , 'id': 'kitty'}]]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a name collision between `enum.Enum` and `sqlalchemy.Enum`?

Comment: @univerio Fixed the name collision, now I get a new error that I cant solve `sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.LookupError) "SpeciesType.Cat" is not among the defined enum values [SQL: 'INSERT INTO animals (id, species) VALUES (%(id)s, %(species)s)'] [parameters: [{'species': <SpeciesType.Cat: 1>, 'id': 'kitty'}]]`. Updated question

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are creating the `Animals` enumeration twice, which means you will have two different enums that happen to have the same names.

Define it only once, and import it anywhere else you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `enum` model should be a subclass of Python's `enum.Enum` and your models column definitions should use `sqlalchemy.Enum`

```
class SpeciesType(enum.Enum):
...

class Animals(Base):
    ...
    species = Column(sqlalchemy.Enum(SpeciesType))
```

Comment: with this configuration, I get  "Boolean value of this clause is not defined"